# Check how many parameters block being passed has, and then invoke yield with different parameters

Tags: ruby

I want to know if something like this is possible, as hash.each does two different things based on arguments passed to block

```
{ "a"=>3, "b"=>2}.each {|k| puts k}

{ "a"=>3, "b"=>2}.each {|k,v| puts k}
```

Both output different things, and not just what's below..

```
a
b
..
a
b
```

I get this

```
a
3
b
2
..
a
b
```

So I want to know if there is a way to get my function to do something custom depending on the number of arguments of block being passed to it.

like this

```
def my_method
   if yield.args==2
     yield("hi","bro")
   else 
     yield("what's up")
   end
end

my_method {|a,b| puts a; puts b;} #"hi" "bro"

my_method {|a| puts a; } #"whats up"
```

Comment: can you elaborate what im looking at more

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your question and see I had misunderstood, so I removed my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the block as a `Proc` and then inspect its parameters:

```
def my_method(&blk)
  blk.parameters
end

my_method {|a|}
# => [[:opt, :a]]

my_method {|a, b|}
# => [[:opt, :a], [:opt, :b]]
```

Note, however, that this is *not* what happens with `Hash#each`. `Hash#each` just follows the `Enumerable#each` protocol and *always* yields *one single item* to the block, which is a two-element `Array` of key and value. Normal block parameter binding then takes care of the rest:

```
def my_method
  yield ['Hello', 'World']
end

my_method {|a| p a }
# ["Hello", "World"]

my_method {|a, b| p a, b }
# "Hello"
# "World"

my_method {|a, b, c| p a, b, c }
# "Hello"
# "World"
# nil
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def my_method(&block)
  if block.arity == 2
    yield("hi", "bro")
  else 
    yield("what's up")
  end
end
```

Also look at the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-arity) since `Proc#arity` has special behavior for default/named arguments, etc.

Comment: You should really be using `Proc#parameters` now. `Proc#arity` as been becoming more and more useless with the introduction of optional parameters, rest parameters, and keyword parameters.

Comment: I would disagree. This is exactly what OP asked. It is concise and doesn't require any further tinkering with the parameters being passed.

Comment: how does `each` does it?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, the way @Jorg explained it. You can see that if you run `{a: 1, b: 2}.each.to_a` it will be converted to array with array of `[key, value]`. It is just that if you want two arguments, the array will be unpacked, if not - the pair will be given in one argument. There is nothing different happening depending on arguments.